# When can I see through water at the beach?

Tags: optics, water, refraction

I have some oblique photographs of sandy beaches. I have added a contour at a hue of 120° to roughly divide reds (sand) and blues (water/sky).

[image: nz]
Source: https://www.stuff.co.nz/travel/destinations/nz/nelson-tasman/300514295
[image: pt]
Source: https://geops.cz/zajezdy/portugalsko/madeira/madeira-a-porto-santo/

The hue of the ocean varies depending on the angle of the light entering the camera. Here is how I understand it:

1. In shallow depths (and steeper incidence angles) the sandy bottom is visible because of light refracting through the water column.
2. In deeper depths (and steeper incidence angles) the colour of the water itself is visible.
3. In deeper depths (and flatter incidence angles) the reflection of the sky is visible.

[image: diagram]

I would like to know under what conditions the hue of the water will be dominated by the colour of the sand. Can I calculate this using the water depth and incidence angle alone?

Comment: You are basically reinventing raytracing algorithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nice beach to analyze! The short answer is yes probably you can get a depth map from a still images, but it is probably not easy.

There is a field called remote sensing and a lot of the work concerns images from satellites, or airplanes and shallow water bathymetry is one area of interest. More recently using drones and looking at shallow water along beaches has become popular. You have a slightly different problem since your camera is at low height, but many of the same techniques would apply. They often will take images in different wavelength bands, or take images with different polarizations to get more information and then do imaging processing. In your case if you took images with a polarizer at different angles it might provide more information.

The ray tracing approach will only get you so far. The problem is that the optical properties of water vary a lot and are also dependent on the amount of suspended particles as well as organic matter. Another issue is that the surface is not a nice flat surface. It is changing with the waves and wind. The illumination is changing with time of day etc.
Different water types have different reflectivities, textures etc.

The approach you are taking by looking at the hue and color changes is actually a good way to start.
Qualitatively it will give you some idea of the depth, but to be accurate and I think you would probably need to go beyond just optical modeling and get some ground truth measurements to calibrate.

Comment: Ray tracing is the concept I was looking for, but I agree that this problem is non-trivial. I am not after the depth, I am more interested in differentiating between exposed and submerged sand. I have adopted a different approach which does not require ray tracing.